# How to access listview in MainWindow.xaml.cs from NServiceBus subscriber handler class

Tags: c#, wpf, nservicebus

I would like to post my NServiceBus subscripiton messages derived from an EventHandler class to a ListView.  The ListView is located inside the MainWindow.xaml of the WPF application.

Here is my NServiceBus subscription event handler code.  Note: I would like to post the event message to the ListView control in MainWindow.xaml.  Any ideas?

```
namespace EventPublisher.SubscriberDemoWPF
{
   public class PublishTrackEventHandler : IHandleMessages<PublishTrackEvent>
   {
      public void Handle(PublishTrackEvent message)
      {
         Trace.TraceInformation(message.GetType().Name);

         //Need to post event message to ListView control in MainWindow.xaml UI;
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml code, which is in the same namespace as my event handler code:

```
<Window x:Class="EventPublisher.SubscriberDemoWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Height="260" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="lstEvents" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the MainWindow.xaml.cs code (typical):

```
namespace EventPublisher.SubscriberDemoWPF
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      //Would normally use listview.items.add("messages"); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your NSB message handler you could fire an event that has been attached to from the Window.  Depending on how you are managing threads, be aware of updating UI elements from threads other than the UI thread.  Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) in MSDN for events in WPF.

Comment: Hi Adam, I have created an event to send the message as you mentioned.  I do not seem to have a handle on the NServiceBus when I run my WPF app.  A breakpoint at my PublishTrackEventHandler class shown above is never triggered when I publish an event.  I am starting the NServiceBus from my App.xaml.cs file, and my configuration file is setup correctly. I tried adding an endpoint.config file, but my handler class never receives the published message.  The handler class does work correctly when I open the NServiceBus.host directly.  Am I missing a configuration for the WPF app to host the bus?

Comment: Here is my code from App.xaml.cs.  Does subscription occur automatically?   public partial class App : Application
{public static IBus Bus { get; private set; }
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
 {base.OnStartup(e);
    Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
    .Log4Net()
        .DefaultBuilder()
        .XmlSerializer()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
        .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(); }}

Comment: Subscription should happen automatically and you should see something in the logs when a subscription is processed or take a look in the subscription storage.  You may need a call to .LoadMessageHandlers() in your code.  As long as the Bus property is maintained for the lifetime of the application, you should have access to the Bus.

Comment: Adam, you are correct, I was missing .LoadMessageHandlers().  It was not added to the WPF subscriber Bus code in the app.xaml.cs class when I autogenerated my endpoint design. I also added a new static event handler to my PublishTrackEvent class and subsribed to it in my MainWindow.xaml.cs code along with code to manage the thread.  It works great!  Thanks for your help.